# Prove $uvu=u$, $v$ unique implies $u$ invertible in a ring $R$

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a ring and $u,v \in R$ are so, such that $uvu=u$ and $v$ is unique. How do I show that $u$ is invertible? R is assumed to have multiplicative identity.
So far I have been able to prove that $u,v \neq 0$. I have also proven that $u$ cannot be a non-invertible element with a one-sided inverse.
Can I get a few more hints?

Comment: $R$ is just a ring?

Comment: It has multiplicative identity.

Comment: Since $uvu=u$, you can write $u(1-vu)=0$ and $(uv-1)u=0$. How you have showed that $u\neq 0$, if the ring was an integral domain would be proved.

Comment: there is nothing here about the ring being an integral domain.

Comment: are you asking me how i proved u not equal to 0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that $uvu=u$ for some unique $v$, note that $u^2vu=u^2$. Consider the quantity : $u(v+uv-1)u$. Note that $u(v+uv-1)u = uvu + u^2vu - u^2 = u + u^2 - u^2  = u$. But then, $v$ was the unique element with this property, hence $v=v+uv-1$ hence $uv=1$.

Comment: Thanks. How did you come to this solution?

Comment: It just flashed through, and seemed correct. So it is.

Comment: And then, of course, you could symmetrically show $vu=1$, if the OP was not already convinced that $u$ wasn't single-sided-invertible.

Comment: Yeah, I did it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, there is another generalization form of this lemma. For an element $u$ in the ring $R$, the sufficient and necessary condition for its invertibility is either (1) $uvu=u$, $vu^2v=1$ or (2) $uvu=u$ and such $v$ is unique.

The necessity is easy to verify and part 2 of the sufficiency has been given. Therefore, I would like to provide the proof of part 1. Since the condition (1) implies that the semigroup $(R,\cdot)$ contains an identity element and $vu^2v=(vu)(uv)=1$, we have $uv=(vu)^{-1}$. Note that $u = uvu = u(vu)^{-1} = u^2v$. Then we have $vu=vu^2v=1$, which implies that $u$ is invertible and furthermore, $v = u^{-1}$.

Comment: Why is $uvu = u(vu)^{-1}$?